# JS/jQuery (Hide div, show div on click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons.

I have two divs I want to show.

Each divs have different content.

I want both divs to only take up the same amount of space on the page.

I want it so on page load, div1 is shown, and if they click link div2, div1 disappears and div2 appears in its place.

What is the best way to go about doing this? and how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All the initial CSS and onload stuff aside and you're using jquery,
I think you're looking for something like

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, when <a href="#" id="button2">show div2</a> is clicked, it doesn't hide div1 and show div2? Any suggestion?

Comment: I had just noticed I forget the quotes around div1 and div2. You'll need those. Also I take it you did give div1 and div2 those ids in the div tags...

Answer (score 2):

page load:

```
$('#div2').hide();
```

click link:

```
$('#div1').hide(); $('#div2').show();
```

Comment: Works great, how could I make this load the contents of a different page on click? Say I wanted div1 to open the contents of div1.php in the div, and div2 opens the contents of div2.php... etc

Comment: check out on ajax and jquery. Its pretty simple actually, a few online tutorials will be good to go with.

Answer (score 1):

see the sample code here... hope this helps :)

http://jsfiddle.net/jpHzk/2/

Note:
Hi Kyle,
I modified my code, added a few lines on it courtesy of jessegavin

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirement that "both divs only take up the same amount of space on the page."

Comment: Modified my post... I hope the idea helps :)

Comment: That will only work so long as the height never exceeds 200px. My answer allows for any height in either div.

Answer (score 0):

In a `click` handler, call `$('#div1').hide()` and `$('#div2').show()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showdiv(id){
    $("#container div").hide(0); //Hide all DIV's within container
    $("#container #" + id).show(); //Show DIV with certain ID
}
```

Then in HTML...

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:showdiv('about');">About Us</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:showdiv('contact');">Contact</a>
```

You should add event listeners, but I guess you did it something like this..

Answer (score 0):

The way that I'd go about doing it is by giving each one a unique ID first (div1 and div2 would suffice).  The div you want hidden should have inside the tag style="display:none"  Then within the tag of the div that you want to click to show the hidden parts, use this type of code: onClick="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';"  Just reverse div1 and div2 on the other for the inverse effect.

This was assuming div1 was hidden and div2 was visible at the start.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly, this is more HTML than Javascript.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

### See working version on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jWVt/

**HTML**

```
<button id="button1">One</button>
<button id="button2">Two</button>
<div id="div1">
    Here is line one<br/>
    Here is line two<br/>
    Here is line three<br/>
    Here is line four
</div>
<div id="div2">
    Here is line one<br/>
    Here is line two
</div>
<p> Here's some other paragraph to show that 
    the divs will take up the same amount of space</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    // Make the divs have equal heights
    var h1 = $("#div1").height();
    var h2 = $("#div2").height();
    $("#div1,#div2").height(Math.max(h1,h2));

    // Then hide the second div
    $("#div2").hide();

    // Then add a click handlers to the buttons
    $("#button1").click(function() {
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();
    });
    $("#button2").click(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();
    });
})
```