# show hidden content

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS/jQuery (Hide div, show div on click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454023/js-jquery-hide-div-show-div-on-click)

I'm new to web development and was wondering what the best way to hide elements was. I'm creating a note taking app and want to have a simple "add note" html form that expands when you click a button. Would I do this with CSS or Javascript?

For example

```
Add Note
```

after being clicked would expand to an html form something like this

```
Note Title: <form>

Note Body: <form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use 'display' property of CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of hiding an element. You can either set the `display` property to `hidden` or you can also hide it using java script. Below given is solution using jQuery.

Html

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" > Add Note</a>
<div id="addNote">
    <!-- Your form goes here -->
</div>
```

You put your Note form in the div having id `addNote`. And the javascript for this is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addNote').hide();
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
      $('#addNote').show();
      $('.clickme').hide();
      return false;
    });
});
```

When the page loads, firstly the `addNote` div is hidden by this `$('#addNote').hide();` and when anybody clicks on the link with the class `clickme` the div having the form is displayed, and the `clickme` button is hidden.

You can add transition effects to `$('#addNote').show()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the jQuery library that have a lot of options to show/hide elements easily in your page. Here's a basic [example](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aBasic_Show_and_Hide), and you can find much more with cool effects (fadeIn/fadeOut, slideUp/slideDown...),

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for attaching the click event handler. When the click event handler executes you can switch with javascript display property of the element from block to none.

like

```
document.getElementById('elementID').onclick = function(){
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('elementHidden');
if(hiddenElement.style.display=='none')
hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
else
hiddenElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: In `document.getElementById`, you don't need the `#` unless you're using jQuery or something. And I believe the event handler is `onclick`. `click` is a native function that allows you to simulate a click on any element. Also, some indentation would be great.

Comment: thanks @Amaan mixed a bit of jquery edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery here is a quick solution:

```
$(function(){
   $("#YOUR ADD NOTE ELEMENT ID").click(function(){
       $("#YOUR FORM ID").toggle();
   })
})
```